# how can i make a window inside this cyclinder?

Tags: modeling, faces, topology

[image]when i press fill it adds one shitty plane that I cant subdivide. Why? I am trying to add a window to this cyclindrical building. Please help before I launch the PC out of the window

previous to this, when trying to cut out the window i had a NIGHTMARE trying to cut it out. the topology seemed to get ruined every time- why?! It seems like such a basic task but it was doing my head in. I would press smooth shading on the cyclinder and it would f##ck it every time? Until i added a subsurf modifier i couldnt get past this problem.. I already had plenty of faces etc and tried both quads and tris?

[image][image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rPmE.jpg)

Comment: Just FYI, software like blender is what I call "arcane" (complicated) because the 3d modeling space is very complex and we demand software that can conquer these subtle modeling challenges.  My computer is nothing more that an extremely fast retarded child; infinite patience and understanding is required.

Comment: yep im learning that, had a long break from Blender and have been quickly reminded of how frustrating it can be when you are trying to perform such a basic task! Im sure it is my fault but things like cylinders just dont seem to work well for me for some reason

Comment: Perhaps include an example blend file and someone might point to the exact solution in your case?

Answer (score 4):

This kind of topology works fine in my opinion:

[image]

If you're trying to create inner subdivisions, it won't work with ngons, it will just create vertices on the edges. Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

But it will work with quads (and tris). Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Another way to subdivide your plane would be to use the Knife Project tool: Create a subdivided grid, delete its faces only, put it in front of your window object, select the window object, switch to *Edit* mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> select the grid, then *Mesh > Knife Project*.

Comment: Im trying to add a window as pictured, why cant i subdivide the plane?

Comment: if it's not a quad it won't create inner edges if this is what your mean

Comment: @moonboots ...or a tri, it creates inner edges on tris and quads.

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann, yes you're right, I'm going to add that, but I don't think it fixes his problem

Comment: so is there any way to subdivide the plane? il attatch another screenshot of the vertices

Comment: yes you can use the Knife Project tool for example

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you need is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> for *Grid Fill*:

[image]

Comment: grid fill didnt work unfortunately